# How to reference a path variable with a space in it in a BAT file?

Tags: batch-file

I saw some other posts on thsi but couldn't get it to work.

I'm using this single line in a .bat file

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s *.inf') do pnputil.exe -i -a %%i
```

The issue I'm running into is the path I have to run this script in has a Space in the name.  (e.g. C:\Windows 10)

The %i variable gets the full path to each INF file which is something like c:\windows 10\driver folder\file.inf

When the pnputil command runs, I just get tons of errors that it's only referencing C:\Windows and dropping everything after the first space.

I tried putting the whole pnputil command in single and double quotes but it didn't help.  I also tried putting just the last %i in single and double quotes but that didn't help either.

Can anyone shed some light as to how I can get the last %i variable to work with the space in it?

Thanks!

Comment: just put quotes around your path: `"%%i"`

Comment: There are tons of similar questions about that on SO, so why not using search?

Answer (score 2):

`for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s *.inf') do pnputil.exe -i -a "%%~fi"`

It's rather a standard for command line utilities to accept quoted strings for a one argument.
Though if it's not working that way you can try also with short path:

`for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /s *.inf') do pnputil.exe -i -a %%~fsi`